# How to make a textarea filled with text (label) every time the button pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a text area record that every time the button is press, it means that it has been recorded and should be showing `record1, record2, record3,` etc. on it.

My goal is that, every button is pressed it will add text to the text area with different text label so that no redundancy.

I tried it with my own with this:

```
private void btnReqstRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JLabel labelthis = new JLabel("record1");
    label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
    TextArea1.add(label);
    TextArea1.revalidate();
    TextArea1.repaint();
}
```

I know it is wrong, but is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

text area is like a mini text editor - you add text to it not other components. Instead of adding labels - just add the text. Something like:

`TextArea1.setText(TextArea1.getText() + "record1")`

This should append record1 to the existing text in the text area.

Answer (score -1):

According to my experience this is possible.

---

```
`private void btnReqstRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
i++;//i class level variable(static) to avoid redundancy
//labelThis initialized earlier should be accessible here
String oldText = labelThis.getText().toString();
oldText += "record "+i;
labelThis.setSize(labelThis.getPreferredSize());
TextArea1.add(labelThis);
TextArea1.revalidate();
TextArea1.repaint();
```

}`